# PHP PDO query only return one incomplete row, it's not about fetch or fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

***Description:***
Hi,guys,i meet a very strange problem about pdo in php,i can **get the right result if i use sqlDbx**(A Database Management Software) search from  Sybase,but if i use pdo to search,i just can only get one incomplete row, also i use fetchAll to see the result. That means the same sql statement through sqlDbx and pdo getting different resutls.

***codes and phenomenon***
*mysql statement:*

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ID,
    HOUR_ID,
    ROUND(100*SUM(pmRrcConnEstabSucc)/SUM(pmRrcConnEstabAtt),6) AS leftAxis,
    ROUND(100*SUM(pmRrcConnEstabSucc)/SUM(pmRrcConnEstabAtt)*((SUM(pmErabEstabSuccInit)+SUM(pmErabEstabSuccAdded))/(SUM(pmErabEstabAttInit)+SUM(pmErabEstabAttAdded))),6) AS rightAxis 
FROM 
    dc.DC_E_ERBS_EUTRANCELLTDD_RAW 
WHERE 
    (DATE_ID BETWEEN '2015-12-11' AND '2015-12-11') AND ERBS='LDF32E44' 
GROUP BY 
    DATE_ID,HOUR_ID 
ORDER BY 
    DATE_ID asc, HOUR_ID asc
```

*execute：*

```
$res = $db->query($sqlCommand, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($res->fetchAll());
```

*result from pdo:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DATE_ID] => Dec 11 2015 12:00:00:000AM
            [HOUR_ID] => 0
            [leftAxis] => 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000
            [rightAxis] => 
        )
)
```

*this sql statement Involvs two formulas:*

```
leftAxis  = 100*pmRrcConnEstabSucc/pmRrcConnEstabAtt
rightAxis = 100*pmRrcConnEstabSucc/pmRrcConnEstabAtt*((pmErabEstabSuccInit+pmErabEstabSuccAdded)/(pmErabEstabAttInit+pmErabEstabAttAdded))
```

(ps:and there are many other formulas,they can get rigth results through pdo and sqlDbx)

***my analysis:***
the problem maybe from rightAxis,because the return result lost the rightAxis,so i try to split rightAxis to:
`100*pmRrcConnEstabSucc/pmRrcConnEstabAtt`
`((pmErabEstabSuccInit+pmErabEstabSuccAdded)/(pmErabEstabAttInit+pmErabEstabAttAdded))`
i execute these two formulas separately and i can get the right results, but if i make them together, it doesn't work.And i try to change the sequence of `*/`, it also doesn't work.
so, could anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You're not saying what your problem is. Expected results?

Comment: I have said what my problem is,the same sql statement executes, but different resutls return,and pod returns the error result,this problem is so strange,so i need to give all the conditions to let you know